# Remove the bottom padding visible on an Android app when the title bar is hidden

Tags: android, html, css

I've been working on a hybrid android application. I have a webview and it loads a local html file which runs the application.
There is a bar on the top of the screen. When I remove the bar, the webview shifts top but doesn't get longer so a white empty space is shown at the bottom of the screen.

[image]
[image]

I removed the bar by adding a custom style.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
```

And this is how I initialize the webview.

```
private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");
    }
```

And my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="gazetedokuzeylul.com.gdeylul.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="431dp"
        android:layout_height="643dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to remove the space either.

Comment: Please show us how the WebView is setup, for example the layout file that defines it. Also - does the html file define width or height in pixels?

Comment: @Thomas I added the code that creates the webview. No html doesn't define a height or width. It is set 100%.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Could you please include the file activity_main.xml (to which R.layout.activity_main refers), too? It's inside res/layout.

Comment: @Thomas yes, I added the activity_mail.xml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try setting both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `"match_parent"`

Comment: Glad I was able to help